# How to create word report using NPOI API in .net

Tags: .net, ms-word, npoi

I want to use NPOI to generate word report based on ".dot" template, but I didn't find any documentation to do that.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is a replace way to create word report based on ".dot".

https://freeword.codeplex.com/

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.LoadFromFile("you.dot");
```

Comment: thank's but i found this before i ask my question: it's not realy free. it's a kind of evaluation for spire product and it shows evaluation message while generating documents!